# Passing parameters in a link in native php

Tags: php, rest, uri

In simple php, I need to implement routing based on the REST API principle. There is a condition that in index.php an array with all uris in the form of strings is stored. when executing a request, an array with a url is read, finding a match and sends the corresponding function call to this uri.

```
$urlList = [
    '/users/list'=>['GET' => ['User'=>'list']], //uri => [method => [class => function]]
    '/users/get/{id}'=> ['GET' => ['User'=>'get']],
    '/users/update' => ['PUT' => ['User'=>'update']],
    '/users/add' => ['POST' => ['User'=>'add']],
];
```

My question is about the parameters that are passed in the form of id. How do I arrange a string so that the string
/users/get/{id}' is read at any number in place of {id}?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You will need to "translate" this into some form of wildcard syntax (so most likely, a regular expression), so that you can compare the current URL and see if it is a match.